# What made this black cluster on a leaf?

Tags: zoology, species-identification, entomology

I found this black slug-shaped thing on a leaf by my pond in western Sweden. It's about 15 mm long, positioned on a vertical leaf (I bent it to take the picture). 
[image]

And I don't even know where to start looking. I was thinking it might be an egg cluster, but can't find anything useful without knowing at least what kind of organism made it.

Comment: @Canheguess I can't see any parts that I recognize as a larva (head, legs) and it's been completely still for at least 24 hours. Possibly a pupa I guess?

Comment: If you see them hatching can you take a photo of that too? I've wanted to see one of these for a long time but never found one.

Comment: Nice picture and good question!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After *a lot* of scrolling through image searches I stumbled upon the answer: this is the egg mass of some sort of horse-fly (Tabanidae). Almost identical egg mass here: http://bugguide.net/node/view/21171

[image]

I'm assuming I won't get a more specific answer than this.

Comment: Thanks for giving an answer yourself. I was really curious. :)

Comment: @AlexDeLarge Yes, me too! (Obviously enough to keep searching, compensating my lacking biology skills with patience.)

Comment: I am impressed! +1

Comment: Try to hatch them! Another nice picture is found here, which includes recently laid and mature eggs: http://www.pbase.com/image/132217026

Comment: @fileunderwater Good idea! But I'm not sure I want to handle a bunch of horse-fly larvae, I would really prefer it if I could watch it happen out where I found it. It's just 50 m from my front door so I could go check it out quite often. Today is the third day that I've seen it in this black "mature" state, so it should happen within a couple of days (6 days seems to be a normal time until hatching) This page http://animaldiversity.org/accounts/Tabanus_similis/ says that they all hatch at once, so it's probably easy to miss!

Comment: @picapica You can put the leaf section in a jar (with very small holes for air). When little horseflies hatch out, you can choose their fate :P

Comment: picapica , if these are horsefly eggs (which I'm pretty sure looking at BugGuide), do you have many in your area? And do they bite you? I've been bitten by deerflies and they hurt! But never horseflies as they're slow and noisy. Easier to avoid

Comment: @Jude Yes, we have quite a few of them around. Mostly to slow to be a problem, but sometimes they manage to bite. The bite is a little bit painful, and then the swelling and itching is worse (but the reaction is very different from person to person).

Comment: Thank you! Any deer flies? I'd assume so if horseflies are around.

Comment: @Jude Those too! In Swedish (at least in my usual vocabulary) we don't have separate words for the different kinds of Tabanidae, so I can't really tell if some are worse than others.